# Function's local variable memory usage not released by ARC

Tags: xcode

I've been programming for iPhone / iPad for three years now and I've met my most puzzling problem. I hope someone will be able to help me because I'm really desperate about finding a solution or, at least, help me get some knowledge I must be lacking. And I did searched and searched and studied.
So, to demonstrate my problem, I created a small simple test application witch has a main list of records saved in the core data (first name, last name and main photo). Associated to each record is a photo album witch can include numerous photos.
The part of the code I'm publishing here is about a process I need to do on each of these photos, starting by converting them from NSData representation in the core data to strings.
My problem is that the local variable "stringPhoto" should be released before the next photo gets processed. Witch doesn't seem to be the case when I check the debugger's memory analyser : it keep growing and growing, proportionally to the number of photos being processed.
Because of ARC, the "release" and "dealloc" methods don't work, and using "stringPhoto = nil" has no effect at all.
I do not wish to turn off ARC because my real apps are quite too big to start managing all the memory usage.

Thank you

```
- (void) convertPhotosToStrings
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = MOC();

    NSFetchRequest *fr = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Photos"];

    fr.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"relatedRecord = %@", self.recordChosen];
    fr.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"idPhoto"
                                                     ascending:YES]];

    self.frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fr managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    self.frc.delegate = self;

    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.frc performFetch:&error];
    if (error) NSLog (@"%@",error);

    for (long int currentItem = 0; (currentItem <= [[self.frc fetchedObjects] count]-1);currentItem++)
    {
        [self convertCurrentPhotoToStringFromCurrentItem : currentItem];
    }
}

- (void) convertCurrentPhotoToStringFromCurrentItem : (long int) currentItem
{
    NSLog(@"currentItem = %li", currentItem);
    sleep (1);  //Allows to chech the memory used by each photo
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:currentItem inSection:0];
    Photos *currentPhoto = [self.frc objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *stringPhoto = [UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithData:currentPhoto.photoThumbnail],1.0) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
    // some process
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect at the end of the loop the program suddenly releases all the extra memory. You need to drain your autorelease pool:

```
for (long int currentItem = 0; (currentItem <= [[self.frc fetchedObjects] count]-1);currentItem++)
{
    @autoreleasepool {
       [self convertCurrentPhotoToStringFromCurrentItem : currentItem];
    }
}
```

Comment: I tryed this solution and it resolved my problem like a charm. Thanks very much.